# Append column if match column from another csv with python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have 2 csv files csv1 and csv2. I was hoping to open csv1 find the matching values in csv2 and then append the matched values onto csv1 then save csv1. Like this

**CSV1**

| ID | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |
| Third | row |
| Fourth | row |
| Fifth | row |
| Sixth | row |

**CSV2**

| ID | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Third | row |
| Fourth | row |
| Sixth | row |

**CSV1**

| ID | Another header | ID from csv2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | First |
| Second | row | N/A |
| Third | row | Third |
| Fourth | row | Fourth |
| Fifth | row | N/A |
| Sixth | row | Sixth |

I've tried using panda merge function but I can't seem to make it work.

`csv1 = pd.merge(TABLE1, TABLE2, left_on='ID', right_on='ID', how='left')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you only want to merge 2 dataframes, as your code is not related to csv reading or writing.

A simple way is to duplicate the `ID` column in the second dataframe before merging, and only keep the relevant columns.

So you could write:

```
csv1 = pd.merge(table1,table2[['ID']].assign(**{'ID from csv2': table2.ID}),
                on='ID', how='left')
```

With your sample data it gives as expected:

```
       ID Another header ID from csv2
0   First            row        First
1  Second            row          NaN
2   Third            row        Third
3  Fourth            row       Fourth
4   Fifth            row          NaN
5   Sixth            row        Sixth
```

(of course this only makes sense if ID are unique in both dataframes...)

Answer (score 0):

If the `ID`s are unique in *both files*, you can try this :

```
TABLE1 = pd.read_csv("csv1.csv")
TABLE2 = pd.read_csv("csv2.csv", usecols=["ID"]).set_axis(["ID from csv2"], axis=1)

out = pd.merge(TABLE1, TABLE2, left_on="ID", right_on="ID from csv2", how="left")

out.to_csv("csv1.csv", sep=",", index=False, na_rep="N/A") #change the sep if needed
```

Output (`csv1.csv`) :

```
ID,Another header,ID from csv2
First,row,First
Second,row,N/A
Third,row,Third
Fourth,row,Fourth
Fifth,row,N/A
Sixth,row,Sixth
```